# How to manage Google Vault Licenses with License Manager API

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-license-manager

Now that Google Apps Vault supports [licensing for a subset of users](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2013/08/google-apps-vault-for-subset-of-your.html), I'd like to be able to manage Vault users with the Licensing API. However, it seems that while [the Reseller API supports Vault](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/how-tos/products) as a product and sku, the [License Manager API does not](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/v1/how-tos/products).

Thinking maybe the documentation was just lagging as sometimes happens, I tried a [licensing.licenseAssignments.listForProduct()](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/licensing/v1/licensing.licenseAssignments.listForProduct?productId=Google-Vault&customerId=Google-Vault&_h=1&) API call with Google-Vault as both the productId and skuId as is used in the Reseller API. It returned a 400 error with the message `Invalid productId: Google-Vault`

Is there a non-reseller way to manage Vault licenses programatically? If not can this be added as an enhancement request?

Comment: This may seem like a silly question - but have you already tried the SKU IDs from the Reseller API w/ the License Manager API?

Comment: No, good question, should have mentioned above. I tried Google-Vault as product and sku as it is in reseller API. A list() operation returns a 400 error with a message of "Invalid productId: Google-Vault"

Comment: This sounds like an oversight or there might be a reason I don't see. Will investigate. Thanks for the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use **VAULT** as the productID and **Google-Vault** as skuID.  See if that works!

Comment: that works. Strange that it would differ from the format used by other products and the reseller API but working is working :-)

Comment: Note that it looks like this has changed. I had verified that using VAULT as the product worked but now it seems to need Google-Vault.

Comment: They now have a page that lists all those values : https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/v1/how-tos/products